# How to display multiple points of one series in tooltip with highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am having a highcharts chart, which is using a HTML-tooltip. That tooltip shows -of course- the values which are available on the x-axis.

```
chart: {
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
            var html = '<table>';
            _.forEach(this.points, function (point) {
                html += '<tr>' +
                    '<td style="color: ' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name + ': </td>' +
                    '<td style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold">' + $currency(point.y, point.point.symbol, 2) + '</td>' +
                    '</tr><tr>' +
                    '<td colspan="3" style="text-align: right">' + point.point.articelno + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            });
            html += '</table>';
            return html;
        },
        style: {
            padding: 10
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the series can have one-or-more points on the same x-line, which I want to display in the same tooltip, but I find no way to do so.

Any ideas for me?

Comment: I think that your tooltip is not in the correct place - it should be outside chart object. You can achieve your goal by iterating over your series and finding point with correct x values. Here you can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4st77zzq/

Comment: In your Fiddle example the mouse-over marker is missing, but the tooltip looks good. I'm gonna try to find the bug in my app.